# What does BONE mean?

Tags: rfc, fips

On page 58 of [RFC 4871](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4871.txt), there is an informative reference to `[BONEH03], "Proc. 12th USENIX Security Symposium, "Remote Timing Attacks are Practical", 2003`.  I'm wondering:  **What does BONE mean?**

I know RFC means "Request For Comments", FIPS means "Federal Information Processing Standards Publication", and ITU means "International Telecommunication Union".  So, I'm guessing BONE has a meaning along the same lines, but I have not been able to figure it out after several internet searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BONEH` refers to [Dan Boneh](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/), one of the  authors of the ["Remote timing attacks are practical"](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/abstracts/ssl-timing.html) paper that RFC 4871 makes reference to.

Comment: Thank you.  It's so obvious now.  Do references in RFC's usually put the author's name in the brackets?  I was assuming the acronyms in the brackets were for collections of works, but I guess not...

Comment: Per [RFC2223BIS-08](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-rfc-editor-rfc2223bis-08#section-2.7): "*We recommend enclosing citations in square brackets ("[ ]"). Simple numeric citations ("[53]") can cause confusing gaps when the list of references is split between normative and informative. A good alternative is to have two separate series, "[n1]", "[n2]", ... "[i1]", "[i2]" for citations to normative and informative references.  Other choices include **author abbreviations, possibly a year ("[Smith93]")**, and some brief encoding of the title and year ("[MPLS99a]").*"

Comment: I couldn't find anything newer explaining the use of author names as citation tags. [RFC 2223](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2223), which was obsoleted by [RFC 7322](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7322), don't mention how citation tags are formatted for documents outside of RFCs, I-Ds, STDs, and BCPs.